# После залива приложения приходит репорт от гугла, что в приложении используется геолокация

Tags: android, location

У меня в приложении даже пермишенов нету на геолокацию, но при заливе приложения приходит репорт от гугла: `access approximate location only in the foreground`. Единственное, что хоть как то связано с локацией - это TimeZone, может ли с этим быть связано? В библиотеках я тоже все проверил - нигде пермишены не запрашиваются. В `Merged Manifest` все проверил, включая манифесты библиотек.

Comment: Откройте манифест и внизу вкладки переключитесь на `Merged Manifest` - так вы увидите его итоговое содержимое с подсветкой что откуда появилось.

Comment: @woesss Проверял, там ничего нету(там библиотеки и проверял)

Comment: @woesss Более того, я  там нашел один пермишен, но удалил эту библиотеку(из ненадобности)